# Use context_processors variable in CustomLabelModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to improve some elements from `Django forms` in my website and I need your help in order to find why my `context_processors variable` doesn't appear in my filter condition.

I have a model (`BirthCertificate`) with two ForeignKeys according to an other model (`Identity`).

- **Identity :** This model contains all informations about town people (lastname, firstname, ...)
- **BirthCertificate :** This model contains all informations about new children and parents informations from Identity model

When I display both ForeignKey choice fields, the list is very long and I would like to filter this ForeignKeys like this :

**Only display people who have the same lastname than the child**

In order to do that, I'm using `CustomLabelModelChoiceField` and I'm making `queryset filter`. I'm using `context_processors` too but I don't overcome to pick up the variable in the `query filter`.

My models.py file looks like :

```
class BirthCertificate(models.Model):

    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Nom de famille')
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Prénom(s)')
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=SEX_CHOICES, verbose_name='Sexe')
    birthday = models.DateField(null=False, verbose_name='Date de naissance')
    birthhour = models.TimeField(null=True, verbose_name='Heure de naissance')
    birthcity = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Ville de naissance')
    birthcountry = CountryField(blank_label='Sélectionner un pays', verbose_name='Pays de naissance')
    fk_parent1 = models.ForeignKey(Identity, related_name='ID_Parent1', verbose_name='ID parent1', null=False)
    fk_parent2 = models.ForeignKey(Identity, related_name='ID_Parent2', verbose_name='ID parent2', null=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

In my views.py file, I have :

```
def BirthCertificate_Form(request) :

    query_lastname = request.GET.get('lastname')
    cache.set('VarLastname', query_lastname, 300)
    print cache.get('VarLastname')

    if request.method == 'POST':
    ....
```

In my context_processors.py file :

```
def cached_queries(request):
    return {'VarLastname' : cache.get('VarLastname')}
```

And my forms.py file looks like :

```
class BirthCertificateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fk_parent1 = CustomLabelModelChoiceField(Identity.objects.filter(lastname = cached_queries), required=False, label = "Père", label_func=lambda obj: '%s %s %s %s' % (obj.lastname, obj.firstname, obj.birthday, obj.birthcity))
    fk_parent2 = CustomLabelModelChoiceField(Identity.objects.filter(sex = "Feminin"), required=False, label = "Mère", label_func=lambda obj: '%s %s %s %s' % (obj.lastname, obj.firstname, obj.birthday, obj.birthcity))
```

But, the query filter doesn't work with my `VarLastname`. I'm getting an empty list.

If I replace :

`CustomLabelModelChoiceField(Identity.objects.filter(lastname = cached_queries)` by `CustomLabelModelChoiceField(Identity.objects.filter(lastname = "test")` it works !

If you have any idea ?

**EDIT :**

With answer from @Udi, my view looks like this :

```
def BirthCertificate_Form(request) :
    # Fonction permettant de créer le formulaire Acte de Naissance et le remplissage

    query_lastname = request.GET.get('lastname')

    if request.method == 'POST':

        parents = Identity.objects.filter(lastname=query_lastname)
        Bform = BirthCertificateForm(request.POST)
        Bform.fields['fk_parent1'].queryset = parents.filter(sex="Masculin")
        Bform.fields['fk_parent2'].queryset = parents.filter(sex="Feminin")

        if Bform.is_valid() :   # Vérification sur la validité des données
            if '_save2' in request.POST :
                post = Bform.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('BC_treated', kwargs={'id': post.id}))

    else:
        Bform = BirthCertificateForm()

    context = {
        "Bform" : Bform,
        "query_lastname" : query_lastname,
    }

    return render(request, 'BC_form.html', context)
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I'm searching why ^^

Comment: If I understand, you want the select list `$("id_fk_parent1")` and `$("id_fk_parent2")` to be changed when the `$("id_lastname")` change. You have to do it with an ajax call, triggered by `$("id_lastname").on("change", function(...))`.

Comment: I will edit completely my post in order to be clearer !

Comment: You are missing a `request.POST`: `Bform = BirthCertificateForm(request.POST)` !!!

Comment: I'm maybe silly (or tired) but : I added `request.POST` in `BirthCertificateForm()`. Previously I had `BirthCertificateForm(request.POST or None)`. I have two `Bform` because I have `if/else` condition. I have to delete `fk_parent1 = CustomLabelModelChoiceField` from forms.py file ? Then, it still displays all rows without take account `queryset`. Could you maybe post the entire view function in your answer with modifications please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **view**, after creating your form instance, modify the field queryset:

```
parents = Identity.objects.filter(lastname=query_lastname)
form = BirthCertificateForm()
form.fields['fk_parent1'].queryset = parents.filter(sex="M")
form.fields['fk_parent2'].queryset = parents.filter(sex="F")
```

There is no need to use context_processors or cache.

After fixing (and some style):

```
def get_form(lastname, data=None):
    form = BirthCertificateForm(data)

    if lastname:
        qs = Identity.objects.filter(lastname=query_lastname)
        form.fields['fk_parent1'].queryset = qs.filter(sex="Masculin")
        form.fields['fk_parent2'].queryset = qs.filter(sex="Feminin")

    return form

def birth_certificate_view(request) :
    lastname = request.GET.get('lastname')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = get_form(lastname, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() :   # Vérification sur la validité des données
            if '_save2' in request.POST :
                post = form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('BC_treated', kwargs={'id': post.id}))

    else:
        form = get_form(lastname)

    context = {
        "form" : form,
        "lastname" : lastname,
    }

    return render(request, 'bc_form.html', context)
```

Comment: I edited my question with your answer, but up to now, I don't overcome to filter `fk_parent` from user `request.get`.

Comment: You have two `Bform = BirthCertificateForm()` occurrences in your code. You will have to deal with both of them.

Comment: I edited your answer and add the solution which works pretty well ;) Thank you ! I was tired yesterday and today I understand what you said ;) This link helps me to understand  : http://www.wkoorts.com/wkblog/2009/08/10/pre-populate-django-modelform-with-specific-queryset/

Comment: What is better with your edit ? just separate in two functions ? Be careful I have to specify two `lastnames` for both parents ;)